# Any tool for investigating server side technologies use by a website?

Tags: website, plugins

Is there any program/plugin than accept a URL and display server side technology that a web site is useing (PHP/ASP, HTTP server, Host OS, database type, ...)?

Opera have an [extension](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/geodata-for-ip/) that shows some server side info, but is there any more complete tool?

Answer (score 1):

This website [Builtwith](http://builtwith.com/) can take a website and display the technologies used by it but I'm not sure it will have exactly everything your looking for

**Update**

Also found a [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396739/how-do-you-determine-what-technology-a-website-is-built-on) with a similar question that might be helpful